# Joint cdf and pdf of the max and min of independent exponential RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Each has an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Define two new random variables by

$W = \min({X,Y}) $

$Z = \max({X,Y})$

Find the joint cdf of $W$ and $Z$, and use it to find their joint pdf.

I know I need to start out by splitting up the event $\{W \le w, Z \le z\}$ as the union of $\{W \le w, Z \le z, X \le Y \}$ and $\{W \le w, Z \le z, X > Y \} $

Comment: The title is wrong since W and Z are not independent.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/565624/75923

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Note that 
$$\{Z \leq t\} = \left[\{Z\leq t\}\cap \{W \leq s\}\right]\cup\left[\{Z\leq t\} \cap \{W > s\}\right]$$
Therefore you will find that 
$$
P(Z \leq t, W \leq s) = P(Z \leq t) - P(Z \leq t, W > s)
$$
where the right side is a reasonable calculation. For example 
$$P(Z \leq t, W > s) = P(X \leq t, Y \leq t, X > s, Y > s) = P(s < X \leq t, s < Y \leq t) =… $$