# The joint density of the max and min of two independent exponentials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X=\min(S,T)$ and $Y=\max(S,T)$ for independent exponential variables $S$ and $T$. Find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? How would you suggest I approach this?

Comment: I think you might find a good direction from this previous post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564417/finding-joint-cdf-and-pdf-of-independent-random-variables/564435#564435

Comment: I took a look at that post but I am still getting confused. So first we have to find the probability that Y is less than some value and X is less than some other (different) value?

Comment: You didn't say whether they're identically distributed.

Comment: They can't be independent, since, for example the probability that the max is less than $1$ is positive, but the conditional probability that the max is less than $1$ given that the min is more than $2$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Remember that the joint density can be found by
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$$

Since $\{X > x\} \iff \{ S > x \text{ and } T > x\}$ and $\{ Y \leq y\} \iff \{S \leq y \text{ and } T\leq y\}$. To find $P(X \leq x, Y\leq y)$ you can notice that 
$$P(Y \leq y) = P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) + P(X > x, Y \leq y)$$
 since either $\{ X > x\}$ or $\{X \leq x\}$. Now, you can solve for 
$$P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(X > x, Y \leq y) - P(Y\leq y)$$
and by the earlier remarks $$P(X>x, Y\leq y) = P(S>x, T>x, S\leq y, T\leq y) = P(x < S \leq y, x < T \leq y) \\= P(x<S\leq y)P(x < T \leq y)$$
The last equality came from the fact that $S$ and $T$ are independent. Put these pieces together and you find that $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = \cdots$ what? And from there $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \cdots$ what?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_{S},F_{T}$ and $F$ denote the distribution function of $S,T$
and $\left(X,Y\right)$.

If $y\leq x$ then $\left\{ X\leq x\wedge Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ S\leq y\wedge T\leq y\right\} $ leading to:

> $F\left(x,y\right)=P\left\{ S\leq y\wedge T\leq y\right\} =F_{S}\left(y\right)F_{T}\left(y\right)$  if $y\leq x$.

If $y>x$ then $\left\{ X\leq x\wedge Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ \left[S\leq x\wedge T\leq y\right]\vee\left[S\leq y\wedge T\leq x\right]\right\} $

In that case $F\left(x,y\right)=P\left\{ \left[S\leq x\wedge T\leq y\right]\vee\left[S\leq y\wedge T\leq x\right]\right\} $

Practicizing the rule $P\left(A\cup B\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\cap B\right)$
we find:

$F\left(x,y\right)=P\left\{ S\leq x\wedge T\leq y\right\} +P\left\{ S\leq y\wedge T\leq x\right\} -P\left\{ S\leq x\wedge T\leq x\right\} $ leading to:

> $F\left(x,y\right)=F_{S}\left(x\right)F_{T}\left(y\right)+F_{S}\left(y\right)F_{T}\left(x\right)-F_{S}\left(x\right)F_{T}\left(x\right)$ if $y>x$.

Based on the distribution function you can find the density if it exists.

This method works in general for independent $S$ and $T$ so can be applied to the special case of independent exponential variables.

Answer (score 1):

If $S,T$ are identically distibuted (the question doesn't say that) and $\Pr(S>x)=e^{-x/\theta}$ then
\begin{align}
& \Pr(\min\{S,T\}>x) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(S>x\ \&\ T>x) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(S>x)\cdot\Pr(T>x) \\[8pt]
= {} & (e^{-x/\theta})^2 = e^{-x/(\theta/2)}.
\end{align}
Thus $\min\{S,T\}$ is exponentially distributed with expected value $\theta/2$.

$\max$ is a bit more complicated than $\min$; maybe I'll return to it.  I posted what you see above because the two answers that had appeared so far were more complicated than they needed to be.

---

Now let's look at the two together.  We have
\begin{align}
& f_{S,T}(x,y) \,dx\,dy \\[8pt]
= {} & e^{-x/\theta} e^{-y/\theta} \, \frac{dx} \theta \,\frac{dy} \theta \text{ for } x>0,\ y>0. \tag 1
\end{align}
For any $(x,y)$, if $x<y$ we'll leave that point where it is, but if $x>y$ we want to interchange $x$ and $y$ so that the smaller one, the min, will appear first in the ordered pair.  The mapping $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$ just takes the part of the first quadrant that's below the line $y=x$ and folds it over so that it's above that line, without changing sizes or shapes, so the Jacobian by which one multiplies is $1$.  And notice from $(1)$ that interchanging the   So just add together the density on the part of the first quadrant that above $y=x$ and the folded over copy of it, getting
\begin{align}
& f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy \\[8pt]
= {} & 2 e^{-x/\theta} e^{-y/\theta}\, \frac{dx}\theta\,\frac{dy}\theta\text{ for } \underbrace{0<x<y}_{\text{This part is different!}}
\end{align}

The asymmetry comes only from the part over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ where it says "This part is different!".

Let's check by integrating out $y$ to get the marginal density of $X$:
\begin{align}
& \int_{y:=x}^{\infty} 2 e^{-x/\theta} e^{-y/\theta} \, \frac{dy}\theta \\[8pt]
= {} & 2e^{-x/\theta} \int_x^\infty e^{-y/\theta} \, \frac{dy} \theta \\[8pt]
= {} & 2e^{-x/\theta} \int_{x/\theta}^\infty e^{-u}\,du \\[8pt]
= {} & 2 e^{-x/(\theta/2)},
\end{align}
which leads to $\Pr(X>x) = e^{-x/(\theta/2)}$, as found above.

Maybe I'll add more later . . .

Comment: @drhab : Well, this is a part of that.  I'll add more . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

1. Notice first that the function $\Phi:(S,T)\rightarrow (X,Y)$ satisfies $\Phi^{-1}(X,Y)=\left\{(X,Y),(Y,X)\right\}$.
2. $\Phi$ t is differentiable at all points but the diagonal (S=T). But notice the diagonal has zero probability.
3. It's Jacobian $J\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ for $S<T$ and $J\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{array}\right)$ for $T>S$. In both cases the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian is $1$.
4. Use the Jacobian method to compute the joint density of $(X,Y)=\Phi(S,T)$. **The only way you are going to learn the method is if you do the computations for yourself.**  See some examples [here](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/change/change.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).
5. Regarding indepence, consider the events $A=[X>1]$ and $B=[Y<1]$. What are $\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)$ ?